# Como mostrar um Facebook Embedded Post por meio de Button Click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Preciso criar um *Embedded Post* em uma página por meio de um evento Click. Estou utilizando a seguinte função:

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <div id="myDiv2"></div>

    <script>
        (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); 
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/michael/posts/046153"></div>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            myLink = "https://www.facebook.com/michael/posts/045847";
            var embPost = '<div class="fb-post" data-href="' + myLink + '"></div>';
            $("#myDiv2").append(embPost);

            myLink = "https://www.facebook.com/michael/posts/045558";
            document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {
                var embPost = '<div class="fb-post" data-href="' + myLink + '"></div>';
                $("#myDiv").append(embPost);
            }
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

O click deste botão insere esta `embPost` em `#myDiv`, mas não gera o *embedded post*, como era de se esperar, por outro lado a `#myDiv2` apresenta o `embPost` completamente renderizado.

Comment: Esse é apenas um trecho do código? A variável **myLink** esta sendo criada onde?

Comment: A variável myLink vem de uma lista recuperada via FB.API, assincronamente. Coloquei um console.log para ter certeza que o seu conteúdo está correto e, de fato, não é aí o problema.

Comment: O `myLink` ele é gerado dinamicamente?

Comment: Sim. O resultado vem de uma FQL, via facebook graph. Este código está dentro de um loop para criar os Embedded um a um...

Comment: Sim, mas a variável `myLink` contém vários Embedded? Pois se esse código está dentro de um Loop, logo as variáveis são reescritas. Não sei se entendi muito bem. Acredito que mais trechos do código poderiam ajudar.

Comment: Não faz sentido rodar isso em um *loop*. As informações na pergunta são poucas, e o código provavelmente foi editado deixando coisa importante de fora.

Comment: Coloquei o código todo. Deixei o loop de fora pois ele não é importante para este estudo.

Comment: Você está testando do jeito errado. O código que postou agora requer o "onReady" ou "setTimeout" ou de algum jeito de aguardar que o script do Facebook seja carregado e executado.

Comment: J. Bruni, já inseri o "onReady", conforme sua orientação.

Comment: Certo... agora mude `$(document).ready(function(){` para `$('#myButton').click(function(){` na sua pergunta - apenas para que o restante do texto da pergunta permaneça coerente sem você precisar re-escrever tudo (pois fala de "clique no botão"). ;-) Ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código do Facebook monta os Embedded Posts que ele encontra na página ao ser executado. Uma estratégia é:

- primeiro montar os divs
- só depois chamar o código do Facebook

Mais ou menos assim:

```
function incluiEmbedPost(indice, link) {
    var embPost = $('<div class="fb-post" data-href="' + link + '"></div>');
    $('#myDiv').append(embPost);
}

function rodaLanceDoFacebookConnect(){
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); 
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}

$(function(){
    var myLinks = ['POST1', 'POST2', 'POST3'];
    $.each(myLinks, incluiEmbedPost);
    rodaLanceDoFacebookConnect();
});
```

---

Outra alternativa abaixo.

Neste caso, usamos a [função `FB.XFBML.parse` do Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) para renderizar o HTML que contém o *embedded post*:

```
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); 
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function incluiEmbedPost(seletor, link) {
    var embPost = $('<div class="fb-post" data-href="' + link + '"></div>');
    $(seletor).append(embPost);
    FB.XFBML.parse(embPost.get(0));
}

$(function(){
    // Chamar a seguinte função para incluir novo post a qualquer momento:
    incluiEmbedPost('#myDiv', 'https://www.facebook.com/michael/posts/045847');
});
```

Comment: O resultado foi o mesmo, infelizmente... a DIV é aninhada corretamente, mas o Embedded Post não é gerado.

Comment: Re-escrevi completamente a resposta, depois que me "caiu a ficha". :-) Por favor, verifique se te ajuda agora.

Comment: Cara, parece praga! O resultado foi exatamente o mesmo. A `div` recebe o conteúdo, mas não renderiza como `embedded post`.

Comment: Digo, o seu código está perfeito e funciona muito bom, mas eu não tenho a lista de links prévia e o array é carregado assincronamente via FB.API...

Comment: Ok. Pesquisei mais e incluí outra alternativa na resposta. Vamos ver se agora vai...

Comment: J. Bruni, funcionou perfeitamente e em todas as situações que eu preciso. Esse `FB.XFBML.parse()` era exatamente o que eu precisava! Obrigado pela insistência.

Comment: Como nada são flores no mundo das integrações, acabei de descobrir que para um post ser embedded, não basta ser público, mas o usuário tem que poder ser Seguido por Todos, também. Estou postando uma nova pergunta para ver se alguém sabe como resolver isso...